# logstash for custom logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Im trying write a grok filter for below logs but getting grokfailure. I'm new to logstash, please help me.

Logs:
msg.repository.routed.ABC_MAS:101::20170526-05:03:08: got  from remote host at t-rate <0.068> and f-size <68> into tmp dir
msg.repository.routed.ABC_MAS:101::20170526-05:03:07: got  from remote host at t-rate <0.068> and f-size <68> into tmp dir
msg.repository.routed.BCD_MAS:101::20170526-00:04:34: sftp connected to 1.2.2.1(msg), timeOut:1000
msg.repository.routed.ABC_MAS:101::20170526-00:04:37: sftp connected to 1.2.2.1(msg), timeOut:1000

Grok pattern which I used:
filter {
  grok {
         match => { "message" => '(?: %{GREEDYDATA:pullpathinfo}):%{NUMBER:thread}::%{NUMBER:date}-%{NUMBER:HOUR}:%{NUMBER:MINUTE}:%{NUMBER:SECOND}: (?: sftp connected to %{IPORHOST:remoteip} %{GREEDYDATA:msg})' }
         match => { "message" => '(?: %{GREEDYDATA:pullpathinfo}):%{NUMBER:thread}::%{NUMBER:date}-%{NUMBER:HOUR}:%{NUMBER:MINUTE}:%{NUMBER:SECOND}: (?: got \<%{GREEDYDATA:filename}> %{GREEDYDATA:rate_size})' }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

To develop grok patterns I suggest you to use [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/). It allows you to build up the grok patterns incrementally.

For the follow log (on of the log lines in your question):

```
msg.repository.routed.ABC_MAS:101::20170526-00:04:37: sftp connected to 1.2.2.1(msg), timeOut:1000
```

the following grok pattern will work:

```
%{USERNAME:pullpathinfo}:%{NUMBER:thread}::%{NUMBER:date}-%{TIME:time}: sftp connected to %{IPORHOST:remoteip}%{GREEDYDATA:msg}
```

The follow changes are relevant:

- The grok pattern has to be exact about every character in the pattern. This is also true for every space between the grok patterns (`%{WORD} %{WORD}` is not the same as `%{WORD}%{WORD}`. In your pattern there was a space too much between `%{IPORHOST:remoteip}` and `%{GREEDYDATA:msg}`.
- `%{USERNAME}` instead of `%{GREEDYDATA}` (GREEDYDATA should only be used for remaining parts in a log line. Even if the pattern USERNAME has a name, which does not fit, the pattern behind it looks like a good fit, because it includes `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+` (but not the colon `:`)
- `%{TIME}` instead of `%{NUMBER:HOUR}:%{NUMBER:MINUTE}:%{NUMBER:SECOND}

I hope this helps.